# for loop works fine with console.log but not innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, innerhtml, console.log

hello i'm very new to javascript so forgive me if the answer seems obvious...

this is my code which is executed at the click of a button in the body

```
function q() { 

    var A = document.getElementById("time_one").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("time_two").value;
    var C = document.getElementById("post_number").value;

    var D = (B - A) / C;

    for ( var x = A; x < B; x = x + D ) {

    document.getElementById("q_box").innerHTML = x + "<br />";

    }


}
```

i'm pretty sure the error is in the for loop... the output is supposed to be a list of numbers between A and B. and changing the innerHTML = to innerHTML += hasn't worked either?

Answer (score 1):

```
function q() { 

    var A = +document.getElementById("time_one").value;
    var B = +document.getElementById("time_two").value;
    var C = +document.getElementById("post_number").value;

    var D = (B - A) / C;

    for ( var x = A; x < B; x = x + D ) {

    document.getElementById("q_box").innerHTML += x + "<br />";

    }

}
```

You should convert the values in `int` and you should use `+=`

Answer (score 0):

With `innerHTML` code inside the `for` loop you are always setting the value with the last time iterated value. Hence, you need to update your code to

```
 for ( var x = A; x < B; x = x + D ) {

    document.getElementById("q_box").innerHTML += x + "<br />";

    }
```

OR

```
var y = "";
 for ( var x = A; x < B; x = x + D ) {

     y += x + "<br />";

    }
document.getElementById("q_box").innerHTML = y;
```

I will recommend you to go for 2nd option, as it is better to set the updated value at once and not to extract the value and update for each iteration.